# Non abelian group with normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Normal Subgroups are subgroups where all left cosets are right cosets.
For abelian groups, all subgroups are normal.

I want to discuss about a non-abelian group whose subgroups are all normal. Please give an example.

Can we give example of a *finite* non-abelian group with same property?

Comment: Lots of the very first examples of groups we know have normal subgroups. What non-abelian groups do you know?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25307/groups-with-all-subgroups-normal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which non-abelian finite groups have the property that every subgroup is normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639448/which-non-abelian-finite-groups-have-the-property-that-every-subgroup-is-normal)

Answer (score 16):

The [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) is a finite, nonabelian group where every subgroup is normal.

Comment: And as the linked page mentions, the term for groups whose subgroups are all normal are called [Dedekind groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_group). They also use "Hamiltonian" for not-abelian Dedekind groups, but I feel like naming schemes like that seem to run against the grain of 20th century mathematics ideas...

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is a finite subgroup of a group $G$ then it has only finitely many conjugates $k^{-1}Hk$ and these all have finite index in $G$ also. Taking the intersection of these subgroups, $N=\cap_{k\in G}k^{-1}Hk$ yields a normal subgroup which also has finite index.

This is a constructive method of creating normal subgroups. However, if $G$ is finite then the subgroup $N$ may be trivial. Note that if $G$ is infinite and simple then the above working implies that $G$ contains no subgroups of finite index.