# an example of a normal group that is not abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone please tell me an example of a normal group that is not abelian? I read that in a normal group every left coset is equal to right coset.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535633/non-abelian-group-with-normal-subgroup

Comment: check the question. I think you want what @Curiosity mentioned.

Comment: You made some confusion. There are no normal groups, but normal SUBgroups of a given group.

Answer (score 1):

What's a normal group? I know only `normal subgroups` of a group. The property you mention is the definition of a normal subgroup.

As an example, the alternating group $A_5$  is a normal subgroup of the symmetric group $S_5$. It is not abelian: for instance
$$(123)(234)=(12)(34),\quad(234)(123)=(13)(24). $$
It is a normal subgroup because $(S_n:A_n)=2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot. I made a mistake. It should have been normal subgroup.

Comment: Btw, it is also a simple group.