# What is so special about the quaternion group that it is the only non abelian group for which every subgroup of it is normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quaternions

If we disregard direct products, we find that quaternion group is the only non-Abelian group which has every subgroup as normal. Is there some deep property responsible for this 'outstanding' property of the quaternion group? [(ref)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639598/688539)

Comment: "only **non-abelian** group"

Comment: Nice save @NoahSchweber

Comment: I think it's just an instance of the law of small numbers: there isn't enough room for non-normal subgroups: those of order 4 are necessarily normal, and there is only one subgroup of order 2.  And there is no room for any other subgroup.

Comment: It says that normality does not imply commutativity. Normality is global whereas commutativity is local.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I suppose that's one.  I would say it comes from properties of Hamilton's quaternions, or if you prefer, how certain rotations "anti-commute".

Comment: @Kimball There are two different questions: one is how come all subgroups of the quaternions are normal? That's what you are addressing. But the post is, how come.the quaternions are the **only** nonabelian indecomposable group where that happens? And I'm saying: because it's the only one where there isn't enough room for things to go badly.

Comment: "Is there some deep property responsible...?" I'm hoping the answer is yes, and I'd be ecstatic to be proven wrong, but my gut and Arturo are telling me *no*.

Comment: In addition to what Arturo Magidin said there is a lot packed into the caveat *if we disregard direct products*. For if all the Sylow subgroups of a finite group are normal, then the group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Effectively the question is thus immediately reduced to a study of $p$-groups. True, there is still work to do to show that $p=2$ and $|G|=8$ is the only exceptional case. I just felt like pointing out an obvious fact :-)